How do I use an enum that contains fields with bytemuck
This is my enum
use anchor_lang::solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey;
use bytemuck;

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Contiguous)]
pub enum PaymentOption {
    Native,
    Token { mint: Pubkey },
}

I have tried using the Contiguous trait but it doesn't support fielded enums.
My Cargo.toml deps
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"
bytemuck = "1.18.0"

Pubkey size is 32 bytes.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example. You should at least specify which external crates and their versions are used, what are your imports and what is a full error returned by the compiler.

You can not implement Contiguous for your type.
The reason for this not that it can't be derived, nothing stops you from manually implementing it. Instead the fact that Contiguous is an unsafe trait, which means that the implementor must conform to rules documented by the library.
To soundly implement Contiguous, you need the following (from bytemuck's docs):


The size of C and C::Int must be the same, and neither may be a ZST.
(Note: alignment is explicitly allowed to differ)

C::Int must be a primitive integer, and not a wrapper type. In the
future, this may be lifted to include cases where the behavior is
identical for a relevant set of traits (Ord, arithmetic, ...).

All C::Ints which are in the inclusive range between C::MIN_VALUE
and C::MAX_VALUE are bitwise identical to unique valid instances of
C.

There exist no instances of C such that their bitpatterns, when
interpreted as instances of C::Int, fall outside of the MAX_VALUE /
MIN_VALUE range -- It is legal for unsafe code to assume that if it
gets a C that implements Contiguous, it is in the appropriate range.

Finally, you promise not to provide overridden implementations of
Contiguous::from_integer and Contiguous::into_integer.



First, the enum would need to be converted from #[repr(C)] to #[repr(Int)] (with Int = u8 for example).
Such enums are stored as a discriminant followed by a C-union of C-structs of variants.
In our case, this would mean that everything with discriminant 0 would allow arbitrary values in the C-union. This however contradicts our rule #3: while all bit patterns correspond to a valid value, they are not unique.
This could be solved by swapping the field order of the enum, and setting Contiguous::MAX_VALUE to one more than the maximal bit pattern of discriminant 0, and thus allowing only one bit pattern for discriminant 1.
What finally dooms us is rule #2:
The type Int must be a primitive integer.
PubKey is #[repr(transparent) and bytemuck::Pod over an [u8, 32], but there is no primitive integer type larger than [u8; 33] to contain it.

Any option to implement it manually? E.g. see the Playground
use bytemuck; // 1.16.3

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct Pubkey {
    _key: i32
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
pub enum PaymentOption {
    Native,
    Token { mint: Pubkey },
}

unsafe impl bytemuck::Contiguous for PaymentOption {
  type Int = i32;
  const MIN_VALUE: i32 = i32::MIN;
  const MAX_VALUE: i32 = i32::MAX;
}


This implementation is not sound. PaymentOption is 8 bytes, while i32 is 4, so it fails to satisfy the first safety requirement of Contiguous.
